# Turn a single row in SQL into a column

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe, transform

I have this table

| dai_total_sum | usdc_balance_usd | uni_balance_usd | comp_balance_usd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54584359.783183105 | 59754640.523722 | 15818895.098874114 | 6035764.061094895 |

and I want to turn it into this table

| Currency | usd_value |
| --- | --- |
| DAI | 54584359.783183105 |
| USDC | 59754640.523722 |
| UNI | 15818895.098874114 |
| COMP | 6035764.061094895 |

I've tried using unpivot but most other examples for it rely on the dataset having multiple rows. But since I have just one row how would I accomplish this task.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: What if your table has 100 rows? what is your expected result then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is:

```
select 'DAI' as Currency, dai_total_sum as usd_value
from table1
union all
:
:
union all
select 'COMP' as Currency, comp_balance_usd as usd_value
from table1
```